# Start ssh service without ssh into the instance

Tags: linux, ssh, amazon-ec2

I got the problem now that there is an EC2 instance that lost key pair file so I followed the instruction in AWS document to replace the key pair file. Turned out that the ssh port is also closed (I used nmap command to check for opening port). Therefore, I couldn't ssh into the server.

I can mount the root device volume to an instance and modify its content. How can I enable or open ssh port without being ssh into the instance?

Answer (score 0):

I finally solved the problem by following these 3 links:

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/244384/accidentally-port-22-got-closed-how-do-i-fix-the-ssh-access

[How to regain SSH access after beeing locked out by iptables?](https://serverfault.com/questions/300566/how-to-regain-ssh-access-after-beeing-locked-out-by-iptables)

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/questions/error-permission-denied-publickey-when-i-try-to-ssh